# problem with gridview method calling

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

Though i am setting in grid view

```
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
```

and cicking on the gridview i am getting the

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

as i am clicking on Delete link it should open the Delete Event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender,GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
```

but its not opening,

please point me where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about your the event arguments, you should use **GridViewDeleteEventArgs** for **OnRowDeleting**. **GridViewDeletedEventArgs** is used for **OnRowDeleted** event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender,GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
```

[OnRowDeleting Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx)

[OnRowDeleted Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeletedeventargs.aspx)

Hope this helps !